# Executing HDFS commands in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Just started Hadoop and wanted to execute all the **hdfs commands** that are listed while giving this command on the command line

```
$ hdfs
```

There are lot of commands that are listed below on executing the above hdfs command.

> Running hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4

Is there any link or any documentation for it.

> Thanks Andrew

Comment: Running Namenode,Datanode,Resourcemanager,nodemanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go through this manual for any help
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/commands_manual.html
hope this helps 
Thanks,
Gladnick